# Module inside of Manipulate Example

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Here is a very nice example from [The Student's Introduction to MATHEMATICA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521717892).

```
Manipulate[Module[{x, y},
  ContourPlot[Exp[-x^2 - y^2] + x y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
   Contours -> 20,
   Epilog -> 
    Dynamic[{Arrow[{pt, 
        pt + {y - 2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) x, x - 2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) y} /. {x ->
            pt[[1]], y -> pt[[2]]}}]}]
   ]],
 {{pt, {.5, .5}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 5]}]
```

Which produces a wonderful demonstration.

[image]

My next step was to try the following:

```
Clear[x, y, f];
f = E^(-x^2 - y^2) + x y;
Grad[f, {x, y}];
```

Then in the next cell, I tried:

```
Manipulate[Module[{x, y},
  ContourPlot[f, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
   Contours -> 20,
   Epilog -> 
    Dynamic[{Arrow[{pt, 
        pt + Grad[f, {x, y}] /. {x -> pt[[1]], y -> pt[[2]]}}]}]
   ]],
 {{pt, {.5, .5}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 5]}]
```

Which gave only this:

[image]

I gave Evaluate a try but that didn't work. So I tried removing the Module.

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[f, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  Contours -> 20,
  Epilog -> 
   Dynamic[{Arrow[{pt, 
       pt + Grad[f, {x, y}] /. {x -> pt[[1]], y -> pt[[2]]}}]}]
  ],
 {{pt, {.5, .5}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 5]}]
```

And that worked.

[image]

But try typing

```
x=12
```

in the next cell and watch what happens to the arrow.

Finally I tried wrapping everything with a DynamicModule to see if it would prevent the x=12 issue in the notebook. First, this cell.

```
Clear[x, y, f];
f = E^(-x^2 - y^2) + x y;
Grad[f, {x, y}];
```

Then:

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[f, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
   Contours -> 20,
   Epilog -> 
    Dynamic[{Arrow[{pt, 
        pt + Grad[f, {x, y}] /. {x -> pt[[1]], y -> pt[[2]]}}]}]
   ],
  {{pt, {.5, .5}}, Locator, 
   Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 5]}]]
```

This only produced:

[image]

As folks know, there has been a lot of discussion on not using Module inside of Manipulate and this is probably a good example of why not, but there is a lot of stuff happening here that I don't understand and could use some discussion explaining some of the issues:

1. Why does Dynamic in the first code just update the arrow and not the contour plot.
2. Why doesn't `f = E^(-x^2 - y^2) + x y;` and `Grad[f, {x, y}];` work in the second piece of code?
3. Why doesn't DynamicModule work in the last piece of code?
4. And what is the best way to protect the arrow if a student type x=12 in their notebook?

**Answers to Questions #3 and #4:**

I should have defined the function f in the body of my dynamic module.

```
DynamicModule[{x, y, f},
 f = E^(-x^2 - y^2) + x y;
 Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[f, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Contours -> 20, 
   Epilog -> 
    Dynamic[{Arrow[{pt, 
        pt + Grad[f, {x, y}] /. {x -> pt[[1]], 
          y -> pt[[2]]}}]}]], {{pt, {.5, .5}}, Locator, 
   Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 5]}]]
```

This works and x is protected.

Comment: You can define f outside the module if you use `f[x_,y_]:=Exp[...]`, and then use 'f[x,y]' inside the `ContourPlot`, and the `Grad`.

Comment: @N.J.Evans. Sorry, that won't work in this situation. We're talking about having several Manipulate activities in a single notebook, not just one. And we need to protect the Manipulate activities from a host of static things inside the notebook.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `Module` and `DynamicModule` are shadowing the global variables `x` and `y` in the example in which you use them. The demonstration is best written without  using either `Module` or `DynamicModule`.

```
Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[f, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Contours -> 20, 
    Epilog -> Dynamic[Arrow[{pt, pt + grad /. {x -> pt[[1]], y -> pt[[2]]}}]]],
  {f, None}, 
  {grad, None},
  {{pt, {.5, .5}}, Locator, Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 5]},
  TrackedSymbols :> {pt},
  Initialization :> (
    f = E^(-x^2 - y^2) + x y;
    grad = Grad[f, {x, y}])]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

Sorry that I was careless about the testing of my code. The issue that you raise in your comment can be fixed by using pure functions. I do need to introduce `Module` in the fix.

My reworking of your example still keeps everything localized, Specifying controls that are non-functioning and invisible, like `func` and `grad`, is a useful trick for creating localized variables in `Manipulate` expressions,

```
x = 12; y = 42; func = 1; grad = 0;
Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[func[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
    Contours -> 20,
    Epilog -> Dynamic[Arrow[{pt, pt + grad[pt[[1]], pt[[2]]]}]]],
  {func, None},
  {grad, None},
  {{pt, {.5, .5}}, Locator, Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 5]}, 
  TrackedSymbols :> {pt},
  Initialization :> (
    func = (E^(-#1^2 - #2^2) + #1 #2 &);
    grad = 
     With[{
       g = Module[{x, y}, 
             Grad[func[x, y], {x, y}] /. {x -> #1, y -> #2}]}, 
       Function[g]])]
```

The code taken from *The Student's Introduction to MATHEMATICA* works because it doesn't define functions, but uses expressions for both the function and the gradient. I don't like that approach because it is too rigidly coupled to a particular function. With my fixed code you only need to redefine `func` to introduce a new function. For example

```
Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[func[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
    Contours -> 20,
    Epilog -> Dynamic[Arrow[{pt, pt + grad[pt[[1]], pt[[2]]]}]]],
  {func, None},
  {grad, None},
  {{pt, {0, .1}}, Locator, Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 5]}, 
  TrackedSymbols :> {pt},
  Initialization :> (
    func = (E^(#1^2 - #2^2) &);
    grad = 
    With[{
      g = Module[{x, y}, 
             Grad[func[x, y], {x, y}] /. {x -> #1, y -> #2}]}, 
      Function[g]])]
```

[image: new-func]

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. Put your code in a new notebook, quit the kernel, run your code, then in the next cell, type x=12 and run the cell. Watch what happens to the arrow. The Manipulate no longer runs properly.

Comment: @David. I believe I have fixed the code so that no global variables can interfere with it.

Answer (score 4):

This is taking your first modification of the original code and just changing the way `f` is defined, then using that function inside the module. It seems to work fine for me.

```
Clear[x, y, f];
x = 10;(*Global values have no effect on Module...*)
y = 12;(*Global values have no effect on Module...*)
f[x_, y_] := E^(-x^2 - y^2) + x y;
Manipulate[
 Module[
  {x, y},
  ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}
   , Contours -> 20
   , Epilog -> Dynamic[{
      Arrow[
       {pt, pt + Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] /. {x -> pt[[1]], y -> pt[[2]]}}
       ]
      }]
   ]
  ]
 , {{pt, {.5, .5}}
  , Locator
  , Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 5]}
 ]
```

1. Your first piece of code does not update the contour plot because you set f in terms of the global variables x and y. Inside the module x and y are scoped uniquely so x becomes `x$1234`, or something, and similar for y. Inside the module f is still a symbolic expression. This is why you should define f as a pure function, using set delayed.
2. Setting f as a pure function will allow you to write `Grad[f[x,y],{x,y}]`, which will work, unless you've set a value for x. That value will be applied before grad evaluates. You have a few options there. You can use `Unique[x]` to generate a symbol with no definitions, and then use that in `Grad`, or just clear x explicitly before calling `Grad`. Or you can use a module to scope x and y for this particular calculation. Which is basically the same thing as using `Unique`, but MMA handles the scoping for you.
3. See 1. The symbols x and y are again localized to unique values within the dynamic module.
4. If you write the function as I have here global definitions of x have no effect on the code inside the module. And you don't have to worry about students defining values for x or y.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. Perform the following: (1) create a new notebook and quite the kernel. Copy your code into a cell and evaluate the cell. Then go to the next cell and enter the function `f[x_, y_] := E^(x^2 - y^2) + x y;` and evaluate this second cell. You will see that the image in your manipulate changes.

Comment: If you keep moving the goal posts no one will ever answer your question. You listed four questions, I answered them. You should write another question about scoping that specifically addresses how to keep all symbols local, because that can be done. It's just not what you asked.