# Comparing unit normal definition in calculus with FrenetSerretSystem

Tags: vector-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm trying to compare the unit normal definition in calculus texts (i.e., $\vec N=\vec T'/\|\vec T'\|$) where $\vec T$ is the unit tangent vector, with the unit normal vector returned by `FrenetSerretSystem`. Using the calculus definition, this works:

```
Manipulate[
 
 Module[{r, unitT, unitN},
  
  r[x_] = {x, Sin[x]};
  unitT[x_] = r'[x]/Sqrt[r'[x].r'[x]];
  unitN[x_] = unitT'[x]/Sqrt[unitT'[x].unitT'[x]];
  
  ParametricPlot[r[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
   Epilog -> { 
     Orange, Thick, Arrow[{r[tt], r[tt] + unitN[tt]}],
     Red, PointSize[Large], Point[r[tt]]
     }, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-4, 4}}]],
 
 {tt, 0.01, 2 Pi - 0.01}]
```

But trying `FrenetSerretSystem`, this doesn't.

```
Manipulate[
 
 Module[{r, unitT, unitN, sys},
  
  r[x_] = {x, Sin[x]};
  sys = FrenetSerretSystem[r[x], x];
  unitT[x_] = sys[[2, 1]];
  unitN[x_] = sys[[2, 2]];
  
  ParametricPlot[r[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
   Epilog -> { 
     Orange, Thick, Arrow[{r[tt], r[tt] + unitN[tt]}],
     Red, PointSize[Large], Point[r[tt]]
     }, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-4, 4}}]
  
  ],
 
 {tt, 0.01, 2 Pi - 0.01}]
```

I get an error such as this:

```
Coordinate {0.01 - Cos[$CellContext`x] (1 + 
Cos[$CellContext`x]^2)^Rational[-1, 2], 0.009999833334166664 +
(1 + Cos[$CellContext`x]^2)^Rational[-1, 2]} should be a pair of numbers,
or a Scaled or Offset form.
```

And this gives a similar error.

```
DynamicModule[{r, unitT, unitN, sys},
 
 r[x_] = {x, Sin[x]};
 sys = FrenetSerretSystem[r[x], x];
 unitT[x_] = sys[[2, 1]];
 unitN[x_] = sys[[2, 2]];
 
 Manipulate[
  
  ParametricPlot[r[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
   Epilog -> { 
     Orange, Thick, Arrow[{r[tt], r[tt] + unitN[tt]}],
     Red, PointSize[Large], Point[r[tt]]
     }, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-4, 4}}],
  
  {tt, 0.01, 2 Pi - 0.01}]]
```

Once I get this repaired, I am going to see the unit normal vector (calculus definition) pointing in the opposite direction of the unit normal vector (`FrenetSerretSystem`) from 0 to $\pi$ and I am wondering why. I think it might have something to do with the fact that the calculus books tend to use the curvature, whereas the `FrenetSerretSystem` uses the signed curvature, but I am still trying to figure out the different directions of the unit normal.

Thanks for the help.

**Update due to m_goldberg help:**

This works:

```
Manipulate[
 
 Module[{r, k, unitT, unitN},
  
  r[x_] = {x, Sin[x]};
  {{k[x_]}, {unitT[x_], unitN[x_]}} = FrenetSerretSystem[r[x], x];
  
  ParametricPlot[r[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
   Epilog -> { 
     Orange, Thick, Arrow[{r[tt], r[tt] + unitN[tt]}],
     Red, Thick, Arrow[{r[tt], r[tt] + unitT[tt]}],
     Red, PointSize[Large], Point[r[tt]]
     }, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-4, 4}}]
  
  ],
 
 {tt, 0.01, 2 Pi - 0.01}]
```

And this works:

```
DynamicModule[{r, unitT, unitN, k},
 
 r[x_] = {x, Sin[x]};
 {{k[x_]}, {unitT[x_], unitN[x_]}} = FrenetSerretSystem[r[x], x];
 
 Manipulate[ParametricPlot[r[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
   Epilog -> {
     Orange, Thick, Arrow[{r[tt], r[tt] + unitN[tt]}],
     Red, Thick, Arrow[{r[tt], r[tt] + unitT[tt]}],
     Red, PointSize[Large], Point[r[tt]]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-4, 4}}], {tt, 0.01, 2 Pi - 0.01}]]
```

Both protect the functions in the modules from being changed when functions with the same name are entered in the same notebook in the global workspace.

Comment: The second of your updated solutions is good, but you don't need to write `k[x_]` since you don't use `k` as a function (you don't use it at all) a simple `k` or any other variable name, say, `notused` will do.

Comment: For the reasons I gave in point 3 of my answer, I do not like your 1st updated solution. You want to keep computations made in the 1st argument given to a `Manipulate` expression to the absolute minimum to insure good performance. The performance hit may not be noticeable in this simple problem, but it is there.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks for the added comments and your wonderful assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This much simpler implementation seems to work just fine.

```
Clear[k, n, t]
r[x_] := {x, Sin[x]};
{{k}, {t[x_], n[x_]}} = FrenetSerretSystem[r[x], x];

Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[r[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
    Epilog -> {
      Orange, Thick, 
      Arrow[{r[tt], r[tt] + n[tt]}],
      Arrow[{r[tt], r[tt] + t[tt]}],
      Red, PointSize[Large], Point[r[tt]]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-Pi/4, 2 Pi}, {-2, 2}}],
  {tt, 0., 2 Pi}]
```

[image: demo]

#### Update

The reason your code produces the error message is because you have a scoping problem

If you were to insert a debugging code into your `Manipulate` expression like so

```
Manipulate[
  Module[{r, unitT, unitN, sys},
    ...
    unitN[x_] = sys[[2, 2]];
    Print[Definition[unitN]];
    ParametricPlot[...],
  {tt, 0.01, 2 Pi - 0.01}]
```

you would see

[image: debug]

Note that on the lhs the independent variable is `x$_` and the rhs it is `x`, so your function definitions for the tangent and normal don't work. There several ways you can fix this. Here are three.

1. Define the functions for `r`, `t` and `n` at top-level as I did in the code given above. This is not a bad solution. It's only real drawback is that the `Manipulate` expression is not self-contained.
2. Define the functions in an `Initialization` clause of the `Manipulate` expression. The functions are still defined globally but, at least, they are only defined once and the `Manipulate` expression is self-contained. This is my recommendation.
3. Fix the scoping problem with a variable injection trick I learned form Mr.Wizard (I am not sure he invented it). Although this will fix the scoping, I do not recommend it because it still leaves the problem that the expressions defining `r`, `t` and `n` are re-evaluated each time the front-end updates the `Manipulate`'s content pane -- a big performance hit.

My recommendation is to use the following code.

```
Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[r[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
    Epilog -> {
      Orange, Thick,
      Arrow[{r[tt], r[tt] + n[tt]}],
      Arrow[{r[tt], r[tt] + t[tt]}],
      Red, PointSize[Large], Point[r[tt]]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-Pi/4, 2 Pi}, {-2, 2}}],
  {tt, 0., 2. Pi},
  Initialization :> (
    Clear[k, n, t];
    r[x_] := {x, Sin[x]}; 
    {{k}, {t[x_], n[x_]}} = FrenetSerretSystem[r[x], x];)]
```

The code that only addresses the scoping problem is:

```
Manipulate[
  Module[{r, unitT, unitN, sys},
    r[x_] = {x, Sin[x]};
    sys = FrenetSerretSystem[r[x], x];
    Function[unitT[x_] = #][sys[[2, 1]]];
    Function[unitN[x_] = #][sys[[2, 2]]];
    ParametricPlot[r[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
      Epilog -> {
        Orange, Thick,
        Arrow[{r[tt], r[tt] + unitN[tt]}],
        Arrow[{r[tt], r[tt] + unitT[tt]}],
        Red, PointSize[Large], Point[r[tt]]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-Pi/4, 2 Pi}, {-2, 2}}]],
  {tt, 0., 2. Pi}]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but I still need to know why my code in my post does not work.

Comment: Really great investigation and an excellent explanation. However, like one of our [old conversations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89486/module-inside-of-manipulate-example) , it doesn't protect r[x] getting changed in the global workspace. Try typing `r[x_]={x,Cos[x]}` after running the code. It changes the image. But your line `{{k}, {t[x_], n[x_]}} = FrenetSerretSystem[r[x], x];` makes my code work and protects r[x]. See update to my post.